# How can I assign Questions columns of database to a variable so I can then assign it to label3 and 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How can I assign Questions columns of the database to a variable so I can then assign it to label3 and label4. Please, can anyone here help me to solve this problem because what I am trying to do is to assign a Questions for both of the answers which are stored in my database. I have selected the answers as stated in select command but how can I assign the questions for those answers to a label 3 and label 4. Help is appreciated. So, far the code is working there is no error but I want help in mentioned points please. Help is appreciated.
As it can be seen in image bellow I have column Security1 and Security2. Basically, I want to assign this to a label like Label3.Text = Security1; Label4.Text = Security2;
image

Comment: could you also add the UI screenshot of the desired result?

Comment: Can you provide bit more information? How the database table look like? What is the business use case? The code you provided is populating SqlDataReader but not using it anywhere? You are selecting data but not using it anywhere. If your SELECT query returns questions columns from the db then you can set their value to lables inside if loop by `Label3.Text = reader.GetString(<<questioncolumn1>>)` and `Label4.Text = reader.GetString(<<questioncolumn2>>)`. Use the appropriate column names in the placeholders.

Comment: I have added image with some explanation above image.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `if` block as following.

```
if (reader != null &&  reader.HasRows)
{
    Label3.Text = reader.GetString("Security1");
    Label4.Text = reader.GetString("Security2");
    newpass.Visible = true;
    confpass.Visible = true;
    Label1.Text = "New Password";
    Label2.Text = "Confirm New Password";
    SqlConnection cons = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
    cons.Open();
    SqlCommand updates = new SqlCommand("update reg set Password='" + confpass.Text + "'", cons);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(updates);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    cons.Close();
    //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Your password has been changed')</script>");
           // Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

This solution is specific to your problem. I see that the code can be improved a lot but depends on your business logic and requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Split your approach in two:

**First**, ask the user for his name. When he enters his name and clicks a button, fetch the corresponding security questions from the database and assign them to labels, e.g. `Label3.Text = reader("Security1").ToString()`

**Second**, let the user enter the answers and test them using your existing code.

Comment: Error 1 'reader' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method' C:\Users\samsung\Desktop\Sogftware worksheets\1\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\forgot.aspx.cs 30 27 WebApplication1    this is the error i get

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using WebForms, first you need to understand how things work:

1. You cannot know the security questions without knowing the username, that means you have two options:

   - Have 2 buttons on a page
   - Redirect to another page
     Either way you will be sending either a POST or a GET parameter containing the username.

*First case notice - WebForms do not like 2 forms on one page, and you would have to separate the answers and fetch them by IDs and then add a onClick event on your second button handling the actual update of the data.*

Then you will fetch it via `Request.Form['username']`, where username is a key defined in your form.

After fetching it you execute the reader with the given username, and then show the question in the database via `reader.GetString("Security1")`, and now you can fetch the inputs and pass them to onClick listener of your update button *( another way if you opted for option no 2 - onsubmit event on form )*.

2. It is really bad to keep passwords and even security answers in plaintext format, even the security answers, google about [Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), essentially what you do is store the hash in the database and compare user input with the hash in the database ( Same input will give same hash ( In some algorithms it won't because it uses a salt, and those algorithms already have built in compare function so you don't have to do the comparison manually ) )

So your html should look something like:

```
<form runat="server">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <asp:Button PostBackUrl="~/postbackurl.aspx" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</form>
```

And your CodeBehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        // Fetching code here
        // ...
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Request.Form["username"]);
        // ...
        Label3.Text = reader.GetString("Security1");
    }
}
```